# getImage by Gatsby Image plugin returns undefined

Tags: gatsby, gatsby-image

I have hero image that I want to query for multiple times and fetch it in different sizes so I can use it in different devices sizes.

My hero image is in

> src/images/hero.png

This is the query code:

```
export const mobileHeroImage = graphql`
  fragment mobileHeroImage on File {
    childImageSharp {
      fluid(maxWidth: 375, maxHeight: 400) {
        ...GatsbyImageSharpFluid
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    mobileHeroImage: file(relativePath: { eq: "hero.png" }) {
      ...mobileHeroImage
    }
  }
`;
```

This is my component's code in index.js:

```
const IndexPage = ({ data }) => {

  // First console log
  console.log(data);

  // Second console log
  console.log(getImage(data.mobileHeroImage));
```

First console log logs the object with the image object:

[image]

**The second console log logs undefined even though there is `mobileHeroImage` object inside of `data`**

The image in multiple dimensions would be passed as an array like this:

```
export function MyImage({ data }) {
  const images = withArtDirection(getImage(data.mobileHeroImage), [
    // I would add more sizes here for different screen sizes
    {
      media: "(max-width: 1024px)",
      image: getImage(data.smallImage),
    },
  ])
  return <GatsbyImage image={images} />
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are mixing concepts from [`gatsby-image`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-image/) (from Gatsby v2 backwards) and [`gatsby-plugin-image`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-image/) (from Gatsby v3 onwards).

Among a lot of stuff, in the new version, they get reduced as `Img` (v2) and `GatsbyImage` (v3). The first one takes a `fluid` or a `fixed` `props` image data like the one you are querying in your fragment (`...GatsbyImageSharpFluid`) while `GatsbyImage` takes the whole `image` `props` data. They are queried differently.

In addition, `getImage` is a helper function, so it's not mandatory despite it is making your code cleaner. The fact is from `GatsbyImage` (v3), that's why it's returning `undefined` in your code.

---

Check the migration guide for further details: https://www.gatsbyjs.com/docs/reference/release-notes/image-migration-guide/

---

That said, you should choose one version or another depending on your requirements. I'd suggest the new version because `gatsby-image` it's currently deprecated (so double-check it and get rid of the deprecated packages).

Following the `GatsbyImage` approach, your query should look like:

```
export const mobileHeroImage = graphql`
  fragment mobileHeroImage on File {
     childImageSharp {
       gatsbyImageData(
         width: 200
         placeholder: BLURRED
         formats: [AUTO, WEBP, AVIF]
       )
     }
  }
`;

export const query = graphql`
  query {
    mobileHeroImage: file(relativePath: { eq: "hero.png" }) {
      ...mobileHeroImage
    }
  }
`;
```

*Note: tweak the query options and parameters as you wish*

Now, your `console.log`s should work.

```
  // First console log
  console.log(data);

  // Second console log
  console.log(getImage(data.mobileHeroImage));
```

As I said, you can omit the `getImage` helper function and use directly `data`.